# Selenium and KendoUI Dropdown

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

Just a note, before flagging as duplicate, I have reviewed many answers and haven't found one that works.

I have a KendoUI dropdown showing a list of states:

[image: The rendered states dropdown]

I can successfully automate the dropdown with Selenium's `Click()` event:

```
        var stateField = driver.FindElementById("stateField");
        stateField.Click();
```

I am unable to select an actual state here.  After the dropdown expands, I have attempted to use SendKeys() to send it down arrows / enter to select an option, but I get:

> WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element

What is the correct approach?  Do I have to use Selenium's JavaScript capabilities here?  I noticed the individual options are not given an ID or a name, so I can't select them via that method:

[image: The individual state items in the dropdown]

Here is the dropdown as seen in the inspector:

[image: Inspector DOM view]